# Position of the block relative to the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery and I am trying to find the position of the block relative to the parent:

```
$("*", document.body).click(function (e) {
    var offset = $(this).position();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#result").text(this.tagName + " coords ( " + offset.left + ", " + offset.top + " )");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gk8z18vg/3/

How to get the correct value? Why is offset left 11

Answer (score 0):

You need to add position relative to the parent container so that the value doesn't concern the position from the entire document but just from the parent. The 11 offset looks like the offset of the container + the multiple borders.

```
#co {
 position: relative;
}
```

Fixes it.

Also note that margin are not concerne when talking about position.

Hope that helps